# Qt: Nesting functions of QTableWidget

Tags: qt, nested, qtablewidget

I have some code that should insert some text into a QTableWidget at the index position the user selected.
Actually, my code is already working, but I have a question to the nesting of the ui-functions.

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem();
item->setText("<--");

int test = ui->tableWidget->selectedItems()[0]->row();
item->tableWidget->setItem(test,1,item);
```

This will work just fine and insert the text at the correct row.
But if I now remove the additional step with the "test" variable and just use the function directly instead...

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem();
item->setText("<--");

item->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->selectedItems()[0]->row(),1,item);
```

....then I get the following error message.

> ASSERT failure in QList::operator[]: "index out of range"

Why is that?
Is it not possible to nest functions of ui-objects?

Comment: Are you sure that your table has selected items at the moment when you call the mentioned line?

Comment: That codeline is triggered by the itemSelectionChanged() slot of that tableWidget. It should be selected at that state.

Comment: `item->tableWidget` ??? shouldn't it be `ui->tableWidget`?